# Get only the image URL from pods file field in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a wordpress site for a client. It has a custom post type built with pods called **The Team** (slug is 'the-team') and inside that a file/image/video field with the name **photo**.

I would like to be able to grab the URL of the upload for that field and use it in a template. I have had success with other pods fields by just using 'the_field('pod_name')' but for the image I get an array of data including the URL.

```
1730, 2, 2021-05-20 14:47:41, 2021-05-20 14:47:41, , Person-name, , inherit, open, closed, , person-name, , , 2021-07-02 15:29:47, 2021-07-02 15:29:47, , 1721, http://localhost/clients/xxx/wp/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/person-name.jpg, 0, attachment, image/jpeg, 0, 1730
```

I only want the URL from that array so I can include it in the src of an image tag.

Any help would be appreciated. Can't find anything on Google or SO for this!

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up figuring this out. The answer was to call the field in the same way and put **guid** on the end:

```
<?php the_field('photo.guid'); ?>
```

Then:

```
<img src="<?php the_field('photo.guid'); ?>" />
```